# Integer.parseInt() throws NumberFormatException with UTF-8 files

Tags: java, integer, java.util.scanner

I need to parse integers from contents of a file.

For testing my algorithms, when I give the contents of a file from a declared string

```
String test = "15 kuruş";
```

Integer.parseInt works fine. But when I read with Scanner class from a UTF-8 file it doesn't work and gives the exception

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "15"

Note: I split the string to "15" and "kuruş" so the parseInt method takes only "15" as argument.

Sample code:

```
    satir = satir.trim();//15 kuruş
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(satir," ");
    System.out.println(tokenizer.countTokens());//2
    String s = tokenizer.nextToken();
    int deger = Integer.parseInt(s);//where the exception was throwed
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. Also, check whether the '1' and '5' are the "normal" ASCII characters, or some wide variant.

Comment: if you split by whitespace, the BOM might be before the 15

Comment: Ok I have edited. I guess it is not normal ASCII characters. As I indicate in the question, when I give a test string it works fine but when I read the same string from file it throws exception.

Comment: Open your File in a hex editor to check that

Comment: @jlordo System.out.print(s) gives 15.

Comment: @jlordo when I remove the BOM it worked fine :) thanks!

Comment: @jlordo can you put it as answer so i can accept it

Comment: @ljordo, guys what do you mean by BOM in here?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov BOM = "Byte Order Mark" Can be present in Unicode encoded files to denote which encoding has been used. Leads to problems sometimes and is therefore ommitted often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your UTF-8 File probably starts with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), you have to read the File with the correct encoding or get rid of it manually.

So when your 15 is not preceeded with the BOM anymore, `Integer.parseInt()` will work.